# Can we have a red-black tree without any red nodes?

Tags: algorithm, tree, red-black-tree

I wonder whether a red black tree should have at least one red node. Also, given a BST, if we can convert it into an RBT, is there a unique way to turn this tree into a red-black tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick glance at the [properties of a red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree#Properties) shows that there is no requirement for any node to be red. The only way red nodes come about is through property 5:

> Every simple path from a given node to any of its descendant leaves contains the same number of black nodes.

This property is also satisfied by any [perfect binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees), so every perfect binary search tree with only black nodes is also a red-black tree. (I'm not sure if the textbook red-black tree algorithms ever produce these, though.)

> Also, given a BST, if we can convert it into an RBT, is there a unique way to turn this tree into a red-black tree?

There is no single unique RBT for an arbitrary BST; there are always multiple equivalent RBTs, except for very shallow trees.